# What large and well known companies directly sell BTC?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

At one point [TangibleCryptography](http://tangiblecryptography.com/) offered direct sales of Bitcoins in exchange to USD wire transfer, at competitive rates.

Is there a list of active trusted companies that offer this service?

Answer (score 1):

We have a long history in bitcoin...

bitinstant.com

We offer many options and transaction types.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an US bank account maybe [Coinbase](http://blog.coinbase.com/post/34357253898/you-can-now-buy-and-sell-bitcoin-by-connecting-any-u-s) is something for you.

Comment: $100 transfer per user doesn't seem practical

Answer (score 0):

In The Netherlands: https://bitonic.nl

They charge quite a fee, but are easy and quick. iDeal (direct bank transfer) supported. I used them once and got my bitcoins in a few minutes.